# BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'validatorFactory' of org.springmodules.validation.commons.DefaultBeanValidator

Tags: java, spring, validation, maven, spring-mvc

I am getting this exception while building the spring MVC project in Maven.

```
Caused by: org.apache.commons.digester.xmlrules.XmlLoadException
    at org.apache.commons.digester.xmlrules.FromXmlRuleSet$URLXMLRulesLoader.loadRules(FromXmlRuleSet.java:201)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.xmlrules.FromXmlRuleSet.addRuleInstances(FromXmlRuleSet.java:177)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.xmlrules.FromXmlRuleSet.addRuleInstances(FromXmlRuleSet.java:142)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.addRuleSet(Digester.java:2161)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.xmlrules.DigesterLoader.createDigester(DigesterLoader.java:80)
    at org.apache.commons.validator.ValidatorResources.(ValidatorResources.java:144)
    at org.springmodules.validation.commons.DefaultValidatorFactory.setValidationConfigLocations(DefaultValidatorFactory.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:785)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:604)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:49)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:74)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractBeanFactory.java:852)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1054)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:843)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:427)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:144)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:163)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:284)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:352)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:241)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:184)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1660)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Config

```
<bean id="validatorFactory" class="org.springmodules.validation.commons.DefaultValidatorFactory">
    <property name="validationConfigLocations"> 
        <list> 
            <value>/WEB-INF/validation.xml</value> 
            <value>/WEB-INF/validator-rules.xml</value> 
        </list> 
    </property> 
</bean> 

<bean id="beanValidator" class="org.springmodules.validation.commons.DefaultBeanValidator"> 
    <property name="validatorFactory" ref="validatorFactory"/> 
</bean>
```

In validation xml:

```
 <form-validation> 
          <formset> 
             <form name="address"> 
                <field property="name" depends="required"> 
                    <arg0 key="info.name" /> 
               </field> 
             </form> 
           </formset> 
   </form-validation>
```

Comment: Please paste the entire stacktrace. And i believe the value of 'validationConfigLocations' property is an XML file which threw the error for some reason while loading. But without the config file and the complete stack trace it'd be like shooting in the dark.

Comment: Please edit the question with additional info. Comments have limits. :)

Comment: Can you check the format/content of validation.xml and validator-rules.xml and make sure they are syntactically valid and no errors?

Comment: @prabugp: I have done that already they are proper.:-)

Comment: please post your validation.xml and validator-rules.xml in their entirety. I believe you're missing the <xml or the <doctype declaration in the beginning or something similar. Because the the apache exception is thrown when there is an IO/SAXException. I'd attach the source for the digester lib and find out what is being thrown.

Comment: @prabugp: I have xml and doc type tag already present there.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have got solution.

In my pom.xml I have changed version of commons-digester to 1.8 from 2.0 and excluded log4j from the dependencies which have log4j.jar present in them.